# PDO-dblib mssql installation on a mac

Tags: php, sql-server, macos, zend-framework, pdo

I'm using zend framework, and I have to connect to a microsoft sql db 2005. I've installed all the needed packages through the packet manager ([homebrew](http://brew.sh/)) following ([this tutorial](http://www.ziqijin.com/setting-up-php-mssql-and-pdo_dblib-for-mac-osx-new-version/)), I've successfully downloaded the version of php5.5 with pdo_dblib. Then the problem started.

1. Is the php installation valid for Zend framework and zend studio too? Since, the error that I was getting when trying to connect to the db hasn't changed at all so there must be a mistake;
2. When I run:

   ```
   php -i | grep -i pdo
   ```

The output is:

```
  API Extensions => mysqli,pdo_mysql,mysql
  PDO
  PDO support => enabled
  PDO drivers => mysql, sqlite
  pdo_mysql
  PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
  pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/mysql/mysql.sock
  pdo_sqlite
  PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
```

So, where is my new installation with php 5.5 and pdo-dblib and mssql?
I'm quite confused...

PS: I'm running OSX 10.9

Comment: Are you trying to connecting from php-cli or php-apache2(in other words from command line or web)?

Comment: i assume php-apache2 as i'm running apache with zend. How do i check that?

Comment: How are you run your code?  Is it on webserver?

Comment: Yes of course, i use apache with zend. It is in this dir: /usr/local/zend/bin/zendctl.sh

Answer (score 1):

I've found a [tutorial](https://lastzero.net/2013/08/howto-install-php-5-5-and-phpunit-on-os-x-via-homebrew/) which explains how to link the new version of php. Specifically what is interesting of it is in those two lines of code:

```
 nano ~/.bash_profile
 export PATH="$(brew --prefix josegonzalez/php/php55)/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

now the command:

```
 php -i | grep -i pdo
```

gives the following output (with pdo dblib):

```
 API Extensions => mysqli,pdo_mysql,mysql
 PDO
 PDO support => enabled
 PDO drivers => dblib, mysql, odbc, sqlite
 pdo_dblib
 PDO Driver for FreeTDS/Sybase DB-lib => enabled
 pdo_mysql
 PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
 pdo_mysql.default_socket => /tmp/mysql.sock => /tmp/mysql.sock
 PDO_ODBC
 PDO Driver for ODBC (unixODBC) => enabled
 pdo_sqlite
 PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
```